# Storing vector of unsigned char in an array gives me std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++

**Function**

```
unsigned char* create(std::vector<unsigned char> array2) {
    unsigned char* array1;
    unsigned int temp = 0;

    std::vector<unsigned char> array3 = array2;
    for (auto i = array3.begin(); i != array3.end(); i++) {
        array1[temp] = *i;
        temp++
    }

    return array1;
}
```

**Call**

```
std::vector<unsigned char> someArray; // This has some data inside
unsigned char* array = create(someArray);
int result = send(fd, array, sizeof(array), 0);
```

This code gives me `std::bad_alloc` error message.

I wonder if `*i` stays in `array1[temp]`, but I am not sure.

What's my problem?

Comment: Ask yourself: What memory does `array1` point to?

Comment: It points to first block of pointer?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. @NathanOliver has given you the answer, but for future reference you could have [simplified](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the problem a little further yourself by attempting to put *one* `unsigned char` into `array1`.

Comment: @John Doe Do you want to build a string from the vector?

Comment: @JohnDoe, it points nowhere, it has not been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

This array:

```
unsigned char* array1;
```

never has any memory allocated for it.

But you then asssign values to memory that isn't allocated:

```
unsigned int temp = 0;

std::vector<unsigned char> array3 = array2;
for (auto i = array3.begin(); i != array3.end(); i++) {
    array1[temp] = *i; // no memory allocated for this!
    temp++
}
```

You need to allocate memory:

```
unsigned char* array1 = new unsigned char[array3.size()];
```

you then have to worry about how and when this memory will be freed.

Comment: Oh, okay. But what if I don't know how big will be the array1? What should I do?

Comment: Use a `std::vector`.

Comment: `char[array3.size()]` insures that it will not be smaller than the origin of the data.

Comment: @M.M, you must talk to the author, but I don't see it, how come?

Comment: @anastaciu i misunderstood your comment I think , never mind